# Ubuntu 14.04 dosn't start Back screen

Tags: 14.04, boot

I deleted Gnome shell and restarted my laptop. After booting I can only see a black screen.
I can't login, can't do  anything really.
I recorded a video of the problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjtZSeOU6FE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I can see that Gnome was your only desktop environment. Now you need to install any desktop environment and a login display manager to get the GUI to work. I didn't face the exact problem. I'm showing 2 methods, hopefully at least one of them will work.

**Method 1**

---

Installing Unity:

1. After booting, when you are getting the black screen, press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to bring the tty1 session.
2. From there you'll be able to login using your username and password in the CLI session.
3. Make sure that you are connected to the internet. If you had an saved wifi that used to connect autometically then it should work this time as well. otherwise connect through a Ethernet cable (LAN). enter this command to make sure that internet is working:

   `ping -c 5 ubuntu.com`
4. Now install Unity and lightdm with this command:

   `sudo apt-get install unity lightdm`
5. When the installation is done, enter this command to set lightdm as the default greeter:

   `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

   From there set lightdm as the default display manager.
6. Now enter this command to start lightdm session:

   `sudo service lightdm start`
7. Now go to the lightdm session using `Ctrl+Alt+F7`. You should be able to work normally from there.

---

If the previous method doesn't work, try this one:

**Method 2**

1. After booting, when you are getting the black screen, press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to bring the tty1 session.
2. From there you'll be able to login using your username and password in the CLI session.
3. Make sure that you are connected to the internet. If you had an saved wifi that used to connect autometically then it should work this time as well. otherwise connect through a Ethernet cable (LAN). enter this command to make sure that internet is working:

   `ping -c 5 ubuntu.com`
4. Now install LXDE and LXDM with this command:

   `sudo apt-get install lxde lxdm`
5. When the installation is done, enter this command to set lxdm as the default greeter:

   `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lxdm`

   From there set lxdm as the default display manager.
6. Now enter this command to start lxdm session:

   `sudo service lxdm start`
7. Now go to the lxdm session using `Ctrl+Alt+F7`. You should be able to work normally from there.

Comment: I used the second method and it worked until I got to the log in screen. After entering my user name and password I click login and then nothing just a blue screen.

Comment: Well, you should have used the first method first. Try the first method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe unity could help you then

try method below

```
sudo apt install unity lightdm
```

Then I hope you may try the same process as the first guy says.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Now you have all requirements, and then start daemon service to begin your desktop

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Finally switch your terminal to tty7

```
Ctrl+Alt+F7
```

Enjoy your unity desktop.